# Is there an algorithm for generating a periodic geometric graph from a set of degrees?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Apologies I am a layman with regards to graph theory and am curious about the problem here as it might relate to materials science (hence $2$ or $3$ dimensions). References and paper recommendations are welcomed.

Given a finite set of degrees, where the number of elements corresponds to the number vertices/unit cell, is provided, is there a specific algorithm to generate a corresponding periodic geometric graph in which no two edges intersect? An example is shown below where the left represents a valid periodic planar (2D) graph composed of the set of degrees {$1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5$}.

[image: 1]

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by **"no edge overlap"** because in 3D for example, this is not an issue ; do you think implicitly to planar graphs ? Besides, what do you mean exactly by **periodic** graph ? A graph with a cylindric structure ? Could you give an example ?

Comment: Sorry but the reference to a "representative volume element" is also very puzzling. You should give more context...

Comment: @JeanMarie, by overlap I am referring to intersections of the edges which could also happen in the 3D case. For simplicity, I have included an illustration of a 2D example. Representative volume element is a common term in my field, but since it seems to of introduced confusion, it has been removed.

Comment: Thanks for the nice illustration. Now I can put a name on it: it is a [toroidal graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_graph) (double periodicity ; otherwise said, your graph is not "drawn" on a cylinder as I thought at first (simple periodicity) but on a **torus**).

Comment: As you can see, there is a lot of litterature on the subject, for example [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220621064_Drawing_Graphs_on_the_Torus).

Comment: A nice little [document](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2013_14/math137b_s2014/math137b_s2014_lecture4.pdf)